# HDF4 Raster File upside down (no CRS) QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, hdf, world-file

I have the following data: [http://fizz.phys.dal.ca/~atmos/SURFACE_NO2_ANNUAL_HDF.zip](http://fizz.phys.dal.ca/%7Eatmos/SURFACE_NO2_ANNUAL_HDF.zip) which is provided by the Atmospheric Composition Analysis Group (alternativley you can go to [the Website of the ACAG](http://fizz.phys.dal.ca/%7Eatmos/martin/?page_id=232) and find the link under "Annual ground-level NO2 mixing ratio ~9:30-11:30 overpass time, in [hdf] format."

The data is provided as .hdf files, which do not contain any information about the CRS. When I load them into QGIS 3.8 or higher (with ArcGIS the problem is the same), the maps are shown upside down. I have found related questions, where people do some work arounds using world files. However, I did not manage to properly do this for my specific problem here.

So the basic question is: can I somehow save the file in a standard CRS like WGS84 EPSG:4326 and put the rasters into the "right" projection?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GDAL driver documentation https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/hdf4.html is not promising.

> Georeference
>
> There is no universal way of storing georeferencing in HDF files.
> However, some product types have mechanisms for saving georeferencing,
> and some of these are supported by GDAL. Currently supported are
> (subdataset_type shown in parenthesis):
>
> ```
> HDF4 files created by GDAL (GDAL_HDF4)
>
> ASTER Level 1A (ASTER_L1A)
>
> ASTER Level 1B (ASTER_L1B)
>
> ASTER Level 2 (ASTER_L2)
>
> ASTER DEM (AST14DEM)
>
> MODIS Level 1B Earth View products (MODIS_L1B)
>
> MODIS Level 3 products (MODIS_L3)
>
> SeaWiFS Level 3 Standard Mapped Image Products (SEAWIFS_L3)
> ```

However, we do know something about the dataset:

- It probably covers the whole Earth between -180 and 180 E, -90 and 90 N
- It appears upside down but left-to-right is OK
- By the metadata that is shown by gdalinfo the CRS is EPSG:4326

That is enough for writing a gdal_translate command that turns the image north-up. Notice that this is not a general solution and is totally based on the assumption that we know the upper left and lower right coordinates.

```
gdal_translate -a_ullr -180 -90 180 90 -a_srs epsg:4326 SURFACE_NO2_010x010_ANNUAL_2012.hdf north-up.tif
```

[image: north-up image made with gdal]

Comment: Genius, thank's a lot!